# Oracle analytic functions - how to get the highest RANKing row?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, window-functions

Test data:

```
create table test (
  grp varchar2(16)
, mbr varchar2(16)
, reading1 number
, reading2 number
);

-- group A: 3 members, 1 duplicate set
-- group B: 2 members, 1 duplicate, one reading NULL
-- group C: 2 members, no repeats, no NULLs 
begin
  insert into test ( grp, mbr, reading1, reading2 ) 
    values ( 'A', 'x', '1.0', '2.0' ) ;
  insert into test ( grp, mbr, reading1, reading2 ) 
    values ( 'A', 'y', '1.1', '2.2' ) ;
  insert into test ( grp, mbr, reading1, reading2 ) 
    values ( 'A', 'z', '1.2', '2.4' ) ;
  insert into test ( grp, mbr, reading1, reading2 ) 
    values ( 'A', 'x', '1.0', '2.0' ) ;
  insert into test ( grp, mbr, reading1, reading2 ) 
    values ( 'A', 'y', '1.1', '2.2' ) ;
  insert into test ( grp, mbr, reading1, reading2 ) 
    values ( 'A', 'z', '1.2', '2.4' ) ;
  insert into test ( grp, mbr, reading1, reading2 ) 
    values ( 'B', 'y', '20.2', null ) ;
  insert into test ( grp, mbr, reading1, reading2 ) 
    values ( 'B', 'x', '20.4', '40.4' ) ;
  insert into test ( grp, mbr, reading1, reading2 ) 
    values ( 'B', 'y', '20.2', null ) ;
  insert into test ( grp, mbr, reading1, reading2 ) 
    values ( 'B', 'x', '20.4', '40.4' ) ;
  insert into test ( grp, mbr, reading1, reading2 ) 
    values ( 'C', 'r', '100.1', '200.2' ) ;
  insert into test ( grp, mbr, reading1, reading2 ) 
    values ( 'C', 's', '100.2', '200.4' ) ;
end;
/
```

See [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=696b02f8fff80ed2c90ef98d6cc22c74).

```
select * from test;
GRP  MBR  READING1  READING2  
A    x    1         2         
A    y    1.1       2.2       
A    z    1.2       2.4       
A    x    1         2         
A    y    1.1       2.2       
A    z    1.2       2.4       
B    y    20.2      NULL      
B    x    20.4      40.4      
B    y    20.2      NULL      
B    x    20.4      40.4      
C    r    100.1     200.2     
C    s    100.2     200.4
```

**Problem:**

Write a query that does all of the following:

{1} Find unique rows.

{2} Find the last 2 members (mbr) of each group (grp).  Assumption: when the members are put into alphabetical order, the last member is the one with the last letter (eg if we have 'x','y','z', the last letter is 'z').  Do *not* hard-code the letter into the query.

{3} Perform the following calculation: when rows are grouped (according to their grp letter), for each row containing the *last* letter: 
reading1 - preceding reading2 ( ie reading2 of the row containing the letter 'y' ), and reading2 - preceding reading1.  Treat NULLs as 0.

Using our sample/test data:

```
-- {1}
GRP  MBR  R1     R2     
A    x    1      2      
A    y    1.1    2.2    
A    z    1.2    2.4    
B    x    20.4   40.4   
B    y    20.2   0      
C    r    100.1  200.2  
C    s    100.2  200.4 

-- {2}
GRP  MBR  RESULT1  RESULT2  RANK_  
A    x    1        2        1      
A    y    -0.9     1.2      2      
A    z    -1       1.3      3      
B    x    18       39.2     1      
B    y    -20.2    -20.4    2      
C    r    100.1    180      1      
C    s    -100     100.3    2 

-- {3} required/final result 
grp  result1  result2
A      -1.0      1.3    -- (result1: 1.2-2.2)     (result2: 2.4-1.1)
B     -20.2    -20.4    -- (result1: 20.2-40.4)   (result2: 0-20.4)
C    -100.0    100.3    -- (result1: 100.2-200.2) (result2: 200.4-100.3)
```

**Existing code:**

This query returns result set {2}.

```
-- {2}
  select
    grp
  , mbr
  , r1 - lag( r2, 1, 0 ) over ( order by grp ) as result1
  , r2 - lag( r1, 1, 0 ) over ( order by grp ) as result2
  , rank() over ( partition by grp order by mbr ) as rank_
  from
  (
    select distinct
      grp
    , mbr
    , nvl( reading1, 0 ) r1
    , nvl( reading2, 0 ) r2
    from test
    order by grp, mbr
  ) ;
```

**Question:**
How can we get to resultset {3}, without using hard-coded values (such as rank_ = 2 in a WHERE clause)?
Not sure whether RANK() is needed (for the final query) at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fail to see the point of a requirements such as avoiding `WHERE rank_ =`, but here it is, without `RANK()`, or hardcoding a constant (still, hardcoding is done by using `FIRST_VALUE`):

```
select distinct grp,
  first_value(result1) over (partition by grp order by mbr desc) as result1,
  first_value(result2) over (partition by grp order by mbr desc) as result2
from (
select
  grp, mbr, 
  reading1 - lag(reading2) over (partition by grp order by mbr) result1,
  reading2 - lag(reading1) over (partition by grp order by mbr) result2
from (select unique grp, mbr,
             nvl(reading1, 0) as reading1, nvl(reading2, 0) as reading2
      from test)
);

GRP                 RESULT1    RESULT2
---------------- ---------- ----------
A                        -1        1.3
B                     -20.2      -20.4
C                      -100      100.3
```

When this is easier to read in my opinion:

```
select grp, result1, result2 from (
select
  grp,
  reading1 - lag(reading2) over (partition by grp order by mbr) result1,
  reading2 - lag(reading1) over (partition by grp order by mbr) result2,
  rank() over (partition by grp order by mbr desc) as rank_
from (select unique grp, mbr,
             nvl(reading1, 0) as reading1, nvl(reading2, 0) as reading2
      from test)
) where rank_ = 1
;
```

Comment: Thanks for giving us two solutions!  Although I was more interested to see the first approach, the second query _is_ a bit easier on the eye (as you wrote).